# Post/Get request not working (AJAX, Flask)

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask, post

I'm trying to create a YouTube scraper webpage (for educational purposes; I would never publish it. Just trying to use it to learn). What I currently have is a web page that has a text box that takes a search query and a search button. When the search button is pressed, the contents of the text box are sent to a Python flask file via an Ajax post request (code below), where I use some libraries to search youtube, and then the Python file prints the search result links to the terminal. What I'd like to happen is for the search results to be displayed on my web page for the user to read, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the Flask Python file to send its findings to the HTML page.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <span>
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/logo.png') }}" style="float: left;" id="logo">
            <input type="text" class="textbox" id="searchbar" style="width: 500px; height: 30px">
            <button style="height: 30px" onclick="performPost()">Search</button>
        </span>

    </center>
    
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script>
    function performPost(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{  url_for('search')  }}",
            data: {"search" : document.getElementById("searchbar").value},
        })
    }
</script>
```

main.py:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

def searchSite(searchInput):

    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : searchInput})
    html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall(r'watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    return (search_results)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', text = "heehee")

@app.route('/index.html', methods=['POST', 'GET']) #NOTE: i just changed this line. It used to say @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
        searchQuery = data.getlist('search')[0]
        searchResults = searchSite(searchQuery)
        searchList = []
        for i in range(10):
            searchList.append("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + str(searchResults[i]))
        
        print(searchList)

        return render_template('index.html', name = "jaaa")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host = '127.0.0.1',
        port = 5001,
        debug = True
    )
```

Output to terminal:
[output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwwP1.png)

Comment: You have two different app.route("/") functions, probably not what you're after

Comment: There are twor routes to the root! u need fix that. After, u can just use the render_template method, passing the list to the html page;  return render_template('results.html', data=searchResults)

Comment: @MatheusBrito how should I go about fixing it? Should I just assign an arbitrary directory location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send an AJAX request, the page is not automatically re-rendered. The developer is responsible for inserting the related data into the page.

The following example shows you how to add the response to the page in a callback.

```py
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

def searchSite(searchInput):
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : searchInput})
    html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall(r'watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    return (search_results)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/')
def search():
    data = request.form
    search_query = data.get('search')
    search_results = searchSite(search_query)
    search_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        search_list.append("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + str(search_results[i]))

    print(search_list)
    return render_template('results.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (./templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <span>
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/logo.png') }}" style="float: left;" id="logo" />
            <form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
                <input type="text" class="textbox" id="searchbar" style="width: 500px; height: 30px">
                <button type="submit" style="height: 30px">Search</button>
            </form>
        </span>
        
        <div id="results"></div>
    </center>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        function handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{  url_for('index') }}",
                data: { search : $('#searchbar').val() },
            }).then(data => {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (./templates/results.html)

```
{% for result in search_list -%}
    <div>
        <a href="{{ result }}">Result {{  loop.index }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor -%}
```

A traditional request to the server results in a page being completely reloaded and rendered. This takes time, blocks the page for the user and makes the execution less smooth, but is done automatically by the browser. An AJAX call, on the other hand, is intended to load individual parts of the page in the background and adapt the page to the circumstances. In this case, to enter the data into the page.
You successfully sent a request but ignored the server's response. `then(data => { $('#results').html(data); }` waits for the server's response and replaces the content of the element with the id `results` with the received HTML data.
Since you only replaces part of the page, you don't need the whole template, just an excerpt, hence the second template `results.html`.
The data transfer is an asynchronous process which, as mentioned, must be awaited. For this, the `then` block, which reacts to a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). One solution is the one mentioned here, the function passed in the `then` block will be called once the task is completed. Another possibility is to interrupt execution and use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to suspend all further commands until processing is complete. However, this requires a definition of the executing function as [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Thank you! This solution works perfectly! If you wouldn't mind me asking some questions:

1. what does the line `then(data => { $('#results').html(data); }` do? It seems like it was something very important I was missing

2. what is the difference between this method and re-rendering, as you put it?

3. why do I need to have a "results.html"?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask them.